# I have entered codes for days 1-7 on the LEGO Star Wars Calendar site and now can't enter any more

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

I have the LEGO Star Wars Advent calendar and have put in the codes up to day 7, however it will not allow me to proceed and put in any more codes from day 8 upwards - are other people having this issue? Can I only "open" so many doors in one day?